# How to convert init script into systemd?

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-18.04

The below init code works on ubuntu 14 however latest Ubuntu does not support init and need to convert this script to work in systemd.

I figured starting the service part however unable to figure out on how to restrict it to only tty2,3; how can I fix this?

(init-code)

```
 # tty1 - getty
    #
    # This service maintains a getty on tty1 from the point the system is
    # started until it is shut down again.

    start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[23] and (
                not-container or
                container CONTAINER=lxc or
                container CONTAINER=lxc-libvirt)

    stop on runlevel [!23]

    respawn
    exec /sbin/getty -n -l /etc/init/banner.sh -8 <port> tty1
```

```
[Unit]
Description=This service maintains a getty on tty1 from the point the system is started until it is shut down again.
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/sbin/getty -n -l /etc/init/bapp_banner.sh -8 <Port> tty1
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Did you mean restricting it to run on `run level` 2 or 3 ? Note, there are no run levels in `systemd`. You have to use a specific `target`. `run level` 2 and 3 refer to the `multi-user.target`.

Comment: @iamuser sure thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no runlevels in systemd, and tty1 are available and managed automagically until the system HAS to HANGUP on them.